# ESP32 Deep Sleep Wakeup Though Touchpad

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to write a program that puts my ESP32 into a deep sleep state, and uses touch input to wake it up. I'm able to put it into the deep sleep state, but as soon as it enters, it wakes up and never calls into the callback function.

Reading the raw data from the touch pad, it idles around 25k, and touch inputs from my hand give it a value of around 180k. The 100k value in the code snippet below is the threshold to where I'm comfortable to determine that a touch has been detected.

I'd like to point out that this is different from ext0 and ext1 wake ups.

```
static void touchsensor_interrupt_cb(void *arg)
{
  ... // code here turns on an LED and prints to serial
}

void setup(){
  ...

  touch_pad_init();
  touch_pad_config(TOUCH_PAD_NUM2);
  touch_pad_sleep_set_threshold(TOUCH_PAD_NUM2, 100000);  
  touch_pad_isr_register(touchsensor_interrupt_cb, NULL, TOUCH_PAD_INTR_MASK_ACTIVE);
  touch_pad_intr_enable(TOUCH_PAD_INTR_MASK_ACTIVE);
  touch_pad_sleep_channel_enable(TOUCH_PAD_NUM2, true);
  touch_pad_set_fsm_mode(TOUCH_FSM_MODE_TIMER);
  touch_pad_fsm_start();
 
  esp_sleep_enable_touchpad_wakeup();

  Serial.println("entering deep sleep");
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
```

I've triple-checked that my circuit is correct. Running on an ESP32S3 Dev Kit v1.0. If there's a better place to post this please let me know.

Comment: You need to declare your interrupt handler to be `IRAM_ATTR`. Otherwise it may not be resident in memory and won't run correctly. You also should not print to Serial from an interrupt handler - you really should do as absolutely minimal work as possible. Best to set a `volatile boolean` flag in the handler and return, and do the work in `loop()`. I'm also not sure your handler will be called even if touch wakes the CPU from deep sleep, as the touch occurred before the handler was set since deep sleep effectively restarts the CPU. But you need to write the ISR correctly for it to possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being this line:

```
touch_pad_sleep_set_threshold(TOUCH_PAD_NUM2, 100000);
```

The threshold here was relative to the raw sensor data. Instead, it should be relative to `raw_data - benchmark`, where (I'm assuming) the benchmark is computed from what it considers the sensor's baseline value. You can get your benchmark using `touch_pad_sleep_channel_read_benchmark`.

Printing out the expression above on raw, unfiltered data gives values like:

```
01:25:10.619 -> 3
01:25:10.696 -> -4
01:25:10.774 -> 3
01:25:10.851 -> -10
01:25:10.930 -> -4
01:25:11.006 -> 20
01:25:11.100 -> -2
01:25:11.177 -> 2
01:25:11.255 -> 1
01:25:11.333 -> 0
```

Where those values oscillate around 0 (the noise in my touch sensor). I changed the line above it to:

```
touch_pad_sleep_set_threshold(TOUCH_PAD_NUM2, benchmark * threshold);
```

Where threshold is `0.2`, meaning I'll consider a "touch" when the ESP32 reads sensor values of 120% of the benchmark value. I hope this helps someone.